# Register pcap handler on monitor mode

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I want to create a `pcap` handler on an interface that is in monitor mode. The interface is generated with `iw` tool in linux. To do that I use `popen`

```
void registerWIMonitor(const char *deviceName) {
    char cmd [1000] = {0x0};
    sprintf(cmd, "iw phy phy0 interface add %s type monitor", deviceName);
    FILE* fp = popen(cmd, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        throwErrorScreen(strerror(errno), REGISTERWIMONITOR);
    }
    pclose(fp);
}
```

Then I register the handler on that monitor `deviceName`.

```
void pcapPrepareHandler(const char *deviceName) {
  char errorBuffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

  if (!(handler = pcap_create(deviceName, errorBuffer))) {
    throwErrorScreen(errorBuffer, PCAP_CREATE);
  }
  if ((pcap_set_snaplen(handler, SNAPLEN)) < 0) {
    throwErrorScreen(pcap_geterr(handler), PCAP_HANDLER_SET_SNAPLEN);
  }
  if ((pcap_set_promisc(handler, PROMISC)) < 0) {
    throwErrorScreen(pcap_geterr(handler), PCAP_HANDLER_SET_PROMISC);
  }
  if ((pcap_set_timeout(handler, TO_MS)) < 0) {
    throwErrorScreen(pcap_geterr(handler), PCAP_HANDLER_SET_TIMEOUT);
  }
  if (!pcap_can_set_rfmon(handler)) {
    throwErrorScreen(pcap_geterr(handler), PCAP_HANDLER_SET_TIMEOUT);
  }
  if ((pcap_activate(handler)) < 0) {
    throwErrorScreen(pcap_geterr(handler), PCAP_HANDLER_ACTIVATE);
  }
}
```

But the above function throws an error on `pcap_activate`. The error buffer shows `That device is not up`.

If I run

```
iw wimon0 info
```

it returns me the results:

```
Interface wimon0
    ifindex 16
    wdev 0xe
    addr 00:26:82:e7:88:82
    type monitor
    wiphy 0
```

which reveals that the interface is created successfully.
I search it a bit more and when I typed

```
ifconfig
```

It did not return me the interface `wimon0`.

If now I run:

```
ls /sys/class/ieee80211/phy0/device/net
```

to see the available devices it returns me the interface `wimon0`. Also:

```
cat /sys/class/ieee80211/phy0/device/net/moni0/type
```

returns me `803` which means that the interface is truly in monitor mode.

My though is that it might not have been register correctly on the system. But I do not know how to do that correctly. Am I missing something?

#### Update

Even if I create an interface with `airmon-ng` I still get this error.

Comment: Try running `ip link dev wimon0 set up`

Comment: @ShmuelH. after `iw phy phy0 interface add %s type monitor` ?

Comment: Yes, you should make sure the interface is active.

Comment: Now I get `no such device` error in `pcap_create` What's up? Also now I don't see the interface when I use `iw`.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comments @ShmuelH. I messed up things. But I continue to get this error even with your recommendation.

Comment: @ShmuelH. it turns out that your command is wrong. The correct format is `ip link set up dev wimon0`. That's solved my problem. I don't get any errors now. If you want create an answer to give you the bountry.

Comment: Oh, I'm so happy to hear that, I tried to think what the problem could be. I will write a detailed answer in the next hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple Answer

Run `ip link set up dev <device>` to set up your device.

### The Problem

This device is not activated. In other words, there is a device, but it is disabled by default.

### Why?

First of all, in Linux, every network device is an Interface. In our case, it is a virtual interface.

By default, interfaces are not marked as `Active / Up`, because in most cases, an activated device would require more resources (e.g. `ARP` service, `DHCP` service, etc).